# Method to parse req with multipart content type in node.js

Tags: node.js, http, express

Is there a way to extract file from http req without saving it on server ?

as there are some parser like **Multer** and **Multiply**  , but they save file on server location first.

Can we parse file in node.js as we do in c# .Net

```
Request.Files
```

Comment: Did you read the `multer` documentation, specifically the part about [memory storage](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#memorystorage)?

Comment: just read that it worked, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by using Multer in memory storage mode.

Like:-

```
var storage = multer.memoryStorage();

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

this will keep file in buffer 
and you can extract file like this

```
app.post('/upload', upload.any(), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.files);       
});
```